# Direct2D/C++ - Offscreen Rendering using Bitmap

Tags: c++, windows, direct2d, off-screen

I already have implemented a Direct2D application for windows desktop application using C++, where I show the graphical results (with points, lines, and ellipses) during the simulation. I keep a buffer for storing the simulation values as long as the simulation remains running, and every time interval I simply plot the values. Right now, the situation is, I draw directly on `Hwnd` (`ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`) like

```
pRenderTarget->BeginDraw() 

for(values of simulation results)
pRenderTarget->DrawLine(....)

pRenderTarget->EndDraw()
```

Now I want use the offscreen rendering/drawing using Bitmap, as I need to store the bitmap as an image on the computer (equivalent to taking/capturing screenshot to store the simulation results). How should I proceed in this case (with/without Direct2D `IWICBitmapFactory` - for later screen capturing)?

1. create `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget pHwndRenderTarget` - using `pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget()`
2. create `ID2D1BitmapFactory pBitmapFactory` - using `pHwndRenderTarget->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget()`
3. Create an empty bitmap `ID2D1Bitmap ID2D1Bitmap pBmp` - using `pBitmapFactory->CreateBitmap()`
4. ?? On this Bitmap should I draw lines? if not, where should I draw lines
5. In the end, between whose `BeginDraw()` and `EndDraw()`, I should place the bitmap?
6. Later at some point, I'd capture a screenshot of this bitmap. Without `IWICBitmapFactory` can I achieve this? Any code samples would be appreciated.